# "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" in IIS

Tags: .net, datetime, iis

I use the `DateTime.TryParse` in an WebApplication.

```
var datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt;
var result = DateTime.TryParse(datetime, out dt);
```

It almost works well!
But sometimes the result will be false!
And when I restart the IIS, then it works will again!

I am in China and my server region is china too.
Many people in china has the same problem,but no one can resolve it.

Comment: "sometimes the result will be false" - tell us what the value of `datetime` is in those situations.

Comment: `datetime` was correct, like `2013-04-15 08:12:12`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to resolve this problem

Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as third parameter or
`CultureInfo("zh-CN")` for china

Comment: is any Bug in TryParse? why I can't use it?

Comment: Tryparse, parses string according to the default culture, in your case which does not seem to be same. so in `ParseExact` you can specify your format on the fly